# CocoaPods: How to set Path for pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am working on integrating the Placed.com iOS SDK into our app. They have some strange way of adding the CocoaPod to the project where you have to manually add the framework *then* run pod install. This is what they state.

[image: Placed Instructions]

I am familiar with CocoaPods but not specifying the 'PATH_TO_FOLDER_REFERENCE_ABOVE'

I have tried to integrate their SDK this way with no success, and I believe it is because I am not setting the path correctly. I did this because in my Finder in the project folder, the folder that contains the needed files are in the root folder.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and what if any is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you, please, add a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you put your project and Podfile in '/Users/William/Desktop/Demo' and those three files(Placed.framework, Placed.bundle, Placed.podspec) in '/Users/William/Desktop/Demo/Placed', Then you should write like as following:
pod 'Placed', :path => './Placed'